# PSQLException: An I/O error occurred while sending to the backend. ... Caused by: java.io.EOFException

Tags: java, postgresql, google-cloud-sql

**Environment**

Database: Cloud SQL(Postgres) on GCP

Application: ServiceA (written in java  8)

Below is the simplified piece of code where the error is happening:

```
for(String id: ids){
   int result = dao.getCountForId(id) // where the error is thrown
   if(result>0){
     ...
   }
}
```

The query issued to Postgres:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t WHERE id = ?
```

The error throw is like below:

```
xxxxx.postgres.PostgresRuntimeException: Failed get count for id 7dddfdsfdsewr345234sd.........
xxxx.postgres.PostgresRuntimeException: Failed get result for id ....
Caused by: org.PostgreSQL.util.PSQLException: An I/O error occurred while sending to the backend.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:339) ~[app.jar:?]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:448) ~[app.jar:?]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:369) ~[app.jar:?]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:153) ~[app.jar:?]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:103) ~[app.jar:?]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor14.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at org.postgresql.ds.PGPooledConnection$StatementHandler.invoke(PGPooledConnection.java:428) ~[app.jar:?]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy40.executeQuery(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.receiveChar(PGStream.java:372) ~[app.jar:?]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2043) ~[app.jar:?]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:312) ~[app.jar:?]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:448) ~[app.jar:?]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:369) ~[app.jar:?]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:153) ~[app.jar:?]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:103) ~[app.jar:?]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor14.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at org.postgresql.ds.PGPooledConnection$StatementHandler.invoke(PGPooledConnection.java:428) ~[app.jar:?]
```

This error happen in production when the number of ids was high. But I am not able to replicate in a test or local environment.

**Attempts**

I thought the cause of the error was a lot of queries issued due to large array ids that caused the connection pools of Postgres to saturate. To validate this hypothesis I created an integration test that saturates the connection pool with a lot of queries like below(simplified version):

```
//FILE_PATH contains the input and expected output for the test
  @Test
    @FileParameters(value = FILE_PATH)
    public test(String taskId, int expected){
        int result = dao.getCountForId(id) 
        Assert.assertEquals(expected,result);
    }
```

The error from the saturated connection pool with a lot of queries is like below:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: sorry, too many clients already
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:525) ~[postgresql-42.2.14.jar:42.2.14]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:146) ~[postgresql-42.2.14.jar:42.2.14]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:197) ~[postgresql-42.2.14.jar:42.2.14]
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49) ~[postgresql-42.2.14.jar:42.2.14]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:217) ~[postgresql-42.2.14.jar:42.2.14]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:458) ~[postgresql-42.2.14.jar:42.2.14]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:260) ~[postgresql-42.2.14.jar:42.2.14]
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664) ~[?:1.8.0_282]
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247) ~[?:1.8.0_282]
    at org.postgresql.ds.common.BaseDataSource.getConnection(BaseDataSource.java:98) ~[postgresql-42.2.14.jar:42.2.14]
    at org.postgresql.ds.common.BaseDataSource.getConnection(BaseDataSource.java:83) ~[postgresql-42.2.14.jar:42.2.14]
```

I search on the logs of GCP for the error `org.PostgreSQL.util.PSQLException: FATAL: sorry, too many clients already` but didn't found any records. It seems that this error is not thrown.

I will appreciate any help or guidance in solving this issue.

Best Regards,
Rando.

Comment: Look for the corresponding error message in the server's log file for the first error.  For the second error, you won't find `org.PostgreSQL.util.PSQLException` in the server's log, that is a decoration added by the client.

Comment: The first  line of error is like below: ```io.dexi.postgres.PostgresRuntimeException: Failed get count for id 7dddfdsfdsewr345234sd```

Comment: Were you able to fix this issue? Can you please give some information on how you did?

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce it and it didn't happen anymore.